# Чат бот по распределению заказов на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть чат в который одна группа людей скидывает
заказы а другая соответственно забирает, есть договоренность, что кто быстрее ответил того и тапки. Проблема заключается в том что чтобы забрать заказ требуется сидеть в этом чате и держать палец над буквой Я, и даже при этом может лагануть инет и кто то на пол секунды быстрее ответит

Нужно создать телеграмм бота в котором "заказчики" будут заполняя форму заявки: место, время, снаряд и другие условия по желанию и все также скидывать заявку. А "исполнители" на день а лучше на несколько заполняют в каком месте, в какое время свободны и на каком снаряде будут работать плюс доп.условия.

- Бот будет из образовавшейся очереди по подходящим условиям в порядке очереди раскидывать заказы
- создавать чат в котором "заказчик" и "исполнитель" уточнить детали
- спрашивать "исполнитель" за 5 заказов в очереди не поменялись ли планы и готов ли он принять заказ если планы поменялись то двигать его в очереди на n позиций
- для всех  вести историю заказов  которую можно посмотреть по запросу * для тех кто скидывает заказы показывать сколько людей работает на каком месте, сколько людей свободно в определенное время и т.д
- Желательно автоматически отслеживать кто скинул мне откат на qiwi кошелек

Основной вопрос заключается в том какими технологиями и знаниями нужно владеть, чтобы решить поставленную задачу и с какой стороны лучше подойти к ее решения.

Comment: Выстроить диалог бота и заказчика по шагам с помощью `bot.register_next_step_handler`, с примерами заполнения и после подтверждения записывать, например, в `SQLite`.

Так же и с исполнителями.

После реализовать логику выбора исполнителя по условиям заказчика и связать их.

Бот не может создавать группы/каналы.

Оплату можно сделать напрямую в чате - https://telegram.org/blog/payments-2-0-scheduled-voice-chats/ru?ln=a#platezhi-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Мы несколько раз решали подобные задачи и создали модуль очереди заказов:
https://metabot24.ru/templates/chat-bot-dlya-raspredeleniya-rabot/

Там довольно замороченный код, который должен учитывать асинхронность процессов.

Вы можете воспользоваться готовым модулем на платформе Metabo24. К сожалению на Python кода нет. Код на PHP сделан и тесно вшит в платформу. Можно прокинуть API.

Могу позвать CTO отписаться в этой теме про алгоритм и все подводные камни, если все еще актуально.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос